# Temporary disable certificate validation

Tags: c#, certificate

I need to consume a web service, but it has a certificate and I need to disable its authentication.

the server side can be a dummy server that we are using it to "simulate" results OR a real third side server which use secured soap headers

i need to be able to disable the certificate validation in the server when invoking the dummy server, but to enable it when invoking the real server (which is not ours)

i saw in some post that the way to disable it is to do this:

```
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
```

which works perfectly.

the problem is that once this line of code is executed i can't seem to "reverse" it

i need something like:

```
if (TestMode)
{
  ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
}
else
{
  //enable certificate validation
}
```

btw, the code is in c#.

any ideas ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to de-register the callback, something like this:

Declare a `RemoteCertificateValidationCallback` reference.

```cs
static RemoteCertificateValidationCallback _callbackTrue;
```

Then in your initialization code, assign it like this:

```cs
_callbackTrue = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Then you can register / deregister the callback when your `TestMode` property changes:

```cs
// in the setter for TestMode, when set to true. 
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += _callbackTrue;

// in the setter for TestMode, when set to false
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback -= _callbackTrue;
```

Just make sure that you only register then callback when the `TestMode` goes from '`false` to `true`' and that you only de-register the callback when it goes from '`true` to `false`'. (i.e. your registrations / de-registrations should be symmetrical)

Comment: thx for the reply. 2 follow up questions: 1.will the ServerCertificateValidationCallback effects all services calls (even for other web-service that i use).  2.**"Just make sure that you only register then callback when the TestMode goes from 'false to true' and that you only de-register the callback when it goes from 'true to false'"** - what will happen if TestMode is allready true and i will do again: ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += _callbackTrue; (i dont have a way to know when the TestMode was changed...i only know it's current status)

Comment: 1 - Yes, all calls. 2. Add a member variable to keep track of whether you have registered the callback or not. Only register if not registered already. Only de-register if already registered.