# How to set headers with HttpClient

Tags: c#, rest, api, postman, dotnet-httpclient

I have in my postman request 2 Headers (which are not Authorization) and I would to get the same values than postman in a c# application. 
Is this a good way to do that?

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.MaxResponseContentBufferSize = 256000;

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("PHASH", "6AD787BEE7E3D76BA9B98829BAEA5EA4");

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("UHASH", 40EA4662B482319F8B21EDC378A09BF78CB364B5970E9F0965F816B8067DCF3A");

var uri = new Uri(url);
var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
```

The result should be an HttpResponseMessage, but it made me this error :

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'An error occurred while sending the 
request.'

Inner Exception
COMException : the text associated with this error code could not be found.

The host name in the certificate is invalid or does not match.
```

I do not know if the error comes because of my code or it's because of the api.

Comment: That's not an HttpClient error. The text complains about a certificate. Are you trying to call an HTTPS url that has a bad certificate?

Comment: It looks like this could potentially be a problem with the certificate associated with the URL you are trying to call

Comment: Yes you're right. I asked the dev section who made the api and the https url has a bad certificate. So I can't do anything if the certificate is not good?

Comment: You can disable SSL cert validation programatically, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26361927/temporary-disable-certificate-validation/26362847#26362847